# Infrastructure error launching Blueprint template on fiware cloud lab

Tags: networking, fiware, blueprint, filab

for testing purposes I'm trying to launch a blueprint instance with the following specs:

- **Tier1:** base_centos_7 + tomcat6 
  minimum of instance of 0 and a maximum of 1 (init value: 0)
- **Tier2:** base_debian_7 + mysql1.2.4

  minimum of instance: 1 and maximum: 2 (init value: 1)

Launching this blueprint template I receive the following error:

> Error: Infrastructure error No entity NetworkInstance found with the following criteria: [name = *mynetname*]

But if I go in the *Networks* tab, I'm able to find *mynetname* in the list and it is with:

Shared: Yes 
Status: ACTIVE
Admin State: UP

Any idea why I receive that error?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to contact the specific FIWARE Lab region administrators. They could check if there is any issue with the selected network.